# how to call a numbered variable in a loop in php?

Tags: php

I know what i have implemented here is wrong i want it to do it correctly that is why asking help here.Don't know whether this is possible or not.

```
<?php
$test1="hello";
$test2="how";
$test3="are";
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    echo $test.$i;
}
?>
```

When i run this i should get `hello how are` .i know string concatenation same thing i want to do it for variable also.Is this Possible, if possible by this i can easily access all those variable. Any help?

Comment: Duplicate of a million other questions, see [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (or better yet, store your values in an array).

Comment: Wouldn't array be better? `$test[1]='hello';$test[2]='how';$test[3]='are'; foreach($test as $val) { echo $val; }`

Comment: no only in for loop i would like to do, Thanks

Comment: Just a question, but why would you like to do this? With all do respect, but this programming logic seems like a rather bad idea to me. If you could provide more framework of what you try to achieve, someone can advise you with code for a better alternative.

Comment: @KimGysen agree with you, seems like a bad OOP, but I've just learnt that it's actually possible to do such thing LOL!

Comment: i already have 10 variable like this series defined in db.that is why i don't want to go with array.i know in array also we can do the same but i want the result in this situation itself,Thanks @Kim Gysen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following syntax:

```
echo ${'test'.$i};
```

Comment: Perfect.can i use more variable like this?  @hsz

Comment: If you put it in your loop, `$i` will change and call next variables. Is it that what did you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is the "array". You can use arrays in PHP like this:

```
$test = array('hello', 'how', 'are');
$len = count($test);
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
   echo $test[$i];
}
```

Comment: i don't want array in this case, Thanks for alternatives.this things will give us more knowledge

Comment: @sun then I guess hsz has your answer.. which is also new to me! +1 for your question! I didn't know that this is possible in PHP!

Comment: Thanks for you appreciation.if possible can you clarify me some doubts in oop so that i can learn it well. @evilReiko

Comment: @sun no problem, what do you need to know about OOP?

Comment: if possible any other chatting kind of interaction(site).so that we can discuss more @evilReiko

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++){
    echo $test{$i};
}
```